# Dictionary inside array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key

I have certain data sets. Example, A,B and C. There are sets of these values. For example:-

```
[A:asd, B:ajs, C:aknd],
[A:sdf, B:gss, C:fdss],
[A:ijq, B:cba, C:jqwd]
```

etc.

Now i want to make a dictionary containing these values as separate dictionaries. For example:-

```
{   
    {
        A:asd,
        B:ajs,
        C:aknd
    },
    {   
        A:sdf,
        B:gss,
        C:fdss
    },
    {
        A:ijq,
        B:cba,
        C:jqwd
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out with this. 
I tried doing this but it's not making a dictionary.

```
for( var i=0; i< n; i++) {
    data += {
                "A":value1,
                "B":value2,
                "C":value3
     }
}
```

Any inputs?

Comment: please add valid data.

Comment: Use an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not make sense in Javascript:

```
{   
    {
        A:asd,
        B:ajs,
        C:aknd
    },
    {   
        A:sdf,
        B:gss,
        C:fdss
    },
    {
        A:ijq,
        B:cba,
        C:jqwd
    }
}
```

If you intend to have an object (dictionary) with integer keys, you could do it like so:

```
var data = {};

for( var i=0; i< n; i++) {
    data[i] = {
                "A":value1,
                "B":value2,
                "C":value3
     }
}
```

Depending a bit on what you're trying to do, an array would likely be a better choice:

```
var data = [];

for( var i=0; i< n; i++) {
    data.push({
                "A":value1,
                "B":value2,
                "C":value3
     });
}
```

Comment: An object with numerical keys starting with `0` which are incremented by `1`. Really?! Use an array instead

Comment: @Andreas That would be the obvious choice, but OP specifically wanted a dictionary, which an array isn't.

Comment: @Schlaus I made an array of dictionaries. That did the trick. Thanks for the input.